# Python WAND convert only first PDF page

Tags: python, wand

I have this piece of code, taking a pdf file as argument and convert it to JPG. My problem is, when the pdf have more than one page wand create image like this : test-0.jpg, test-1.jpg etc..

```
 with Img(filename=args['pdf'] + file, resolution=300) as pic:
        pic.compression_quality = 100
        pic.save(filename='images/test.jpg')
```

How could I say to wand to just convert the first page of the given pdf ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easiest way would be to append `[0]` to the filename.

```py
with Img(filename=args['pdf'] + file + '[0]', resolution=300) as pic:
```

Or you can use `pic.sequence`, but that would be slower as it would require all the pages to be decoded.

```py
with Img(filename=args['pdf'] + file, resolution=300) as pic:
    with Img(pic.sequence[0]) as first_page:
        first_page.save(filename='images/test.jpg')
```